# processing update module not running

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo, openerp-7

this is actualy still connected with my previous questions, this is about update module. i did update my module through putty, this is the script, i run from user openerp :

```
sudo /opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp-server -c /etc/openerp-server.conf -d database_name -u all
```

When i executed that script, it was just stopped, not running at all, no result, or even error. i check in error log, there was nothing in error log.
i did correct with my openerp-server.conf. This openerp is the new one because the old one i had already uninstalled. what wrong with my openerp? i really need your help guys..! 
my boss will punish me because of this..

Comment: Replace the `log_level` line in your `openerp-server.conf` file with the line `log_level = debug`. Run again the server and check if something is written in the log file

Comment: You should see a hundreds of new lines with updating operations

Comment: And it's not recommendable run the server with `sudo`, I think it's not possible